# Can't read frame buffer colormap information using ioctl on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, framebuffer

I am working on Raspberry Pi 4, with raspios bullseye-arm-64-lite (version 11).

I want to configure the frame buffer to 8-bits per pixel and use a custom colormap.

I configured the frame buffer to 8-bits per pixel. I could read the fixed and variable information about the frame buffer correctly using ICOTL functions in my C code, but could not read colormap information. While trying to read colormap info, the IOCTL call returns -1.

I added the user to video group and set the frame buffer to 1280x1024 resolution with 8-bit bitdepth using fbset command as follows.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ fbset -fb /dev/fb0 -g 1280 1024 1280 1024 8
```

Here is the output of fbset -i command.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ fbset -i

mode "1280x1024"
    geometry 1280 1024 1280 1024 8
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/0,8/0,8/0,0/0
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : BCM2708 FB
    Address     : 0x3ea87000
    Size        : 1310720
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : PSEUDOCOLOR
    XPanStep    : 1
    YPanStep    : 1
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 1280
    Accelerator : No
```

Here is the my C code.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

static struct fb_fix_screeninfo  fb_fix;
static struct fb_var_screeninfo  fb_var;
static int                       fb;

static unsigned short            ored[256], ogreen[256], oblue[256];
static struct fb_cmap            ocmap = { 0, 256, ored, ogreen, oblue };

int main()
{
    int fp = open ("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (fp < 0){
        printf("Error : Can not open framebuffer device/n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Get fixed info about fb
    if (ioctl(fp,FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO,&fb_fix)){
        printf("Error reading fixed information/n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Get variable info about fb
    if (ioctl(fp,FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO,&fb_var)){
        printf("Error reading variable information/n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    printf("--- FB info ---\n");
    printf("FB_VISUAL : %u \nFB_BITS_PER_PIXEL : %u \n\n", fb_fix.visual, fb_var.bits_per_pixel);
    
    // Get info about cmap
    int i = ioctl(fp,FBIOGETCMAP,&ocmap);
    if (i == -1){
        printf("Error reading cmap information\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And, here is the output of C code.

```
--- FB info ---
FB_VISUAL : 3
FB_BITS_PER_PIXEL : 8

Error reading cmap information
```

After looking at many sources including [fbida](https://github.com/kraxel/fbida/blob/master/fbtools.c), [trinity](https://github.com/kernelslacker/trinity/blob/master/ioctls/framebuffer.c) and [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.1-rc4/fb/internals.html), I believe that I am using the IOCTL calls in right way, but still can't figure out why "ioctl(fp,FBIOGETCMAP,&ocmap);" returns -1.

I would greatly appreciate any help in this direction.

Comment: I'm finding some references online to `FBIOGETCMAP` not being implemented on the RPi.  Do you actually need this?  Using `FBIOPUTCMAP` to set the palette apparently works.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper . It seems you are right. `FBIOGETCMAP` does not work but I can set my custom color palette with `FBIOPUTCMAP`. However, I don't clearly undestand how to write color values in my custom color palette. The red, green and blue fields in the color palette (`fb_cmap` structure) are 16-bit each. For my custom colormap, red, green and blue values range from 0 to 255. I wrote values in range 0 to 255 in the red, green and blue fileds of `fb_cmap` structure, but the screen remains black. I think I am not writing the color values properly. Anyone knows of any helpful resource?

Comment: If the fields are 16-bit, I would assume they're in the range 0..65535 - using 0..255 would result in everything being so close to zero that you probably couldn't distinguish it from black.  Try shifting the values left by 8 bits.